# At a glance can anyone tell me why this Action is so slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, json, recursion

This thing was not noticed to be slow at first because there were not many 'tree nodes' in the database. Now it's really slow, at a glance is there anything major that is wrong with this? I really need to optimize it and before I rework the entire thing I was wondering if anything stands out as being the real pain point. I have narrowed down the slow part to a recursive repository function which is the last thing on this post, I have to define a few things leading up to it though... good luck. ***(NOTE: I did not write this, I was just put on damage control and I am trying to wrap my head around it.)***

A few things to be understood first:

The JsTreeNode definition:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace App.Models
{
    public class JsTreeNode
    {
        public JsTreeNode()
        {
        }

        public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public List<JsTreeNode> children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Attributes
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string rel { get; set; }
        public string mdata { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string complete { get; set; }
        public string edit { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string resourceAccountID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string title {get;set;}
        public string icon {get;set;}
    } 
}
```

Now the TreeNodes table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TreeNodes](
    [TreeNodeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TreeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentNodeID] [int] NULL,
    [ResourceID] [int] NULL,
    [NodeOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NodeName] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [CreateBy] [int] NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifyBy] [int] NULL,
    [ModifyDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TreeRevisionID] [int] NULL,
```

The tree revisions table definition...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TreeRevisions](
    [TreeRevisionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TreeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [text] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifyBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModifyDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

Now here is the Get Action itself that is taking 20-25 seconds, you can see in there that it calls repository function that I have defined further down the this thread.

```
public ContentResult Get(string target,int id)
        {
            int revisionID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["revisionID"]);
            int tempUserID = (Request.QueryString["userID"] != null)
                                 ? Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["userID"])
                                 : UserID;

            var nodesList = new List<JsTreeNode>();
            if(target.Contains("tree"))
            {
                tree tree = _treeRepository.GettreeByID(id);

                var cnode = new JsTreeNode
                                       {
                                           attributes = new Attributes {id = "0",title = tree.treeName},
                                           data = new Data {title = tree.treeName},
                                           children = _treeNodesRepository.GetNodesBytreeID(id, null,revisionID),
                                           state = "open"
                                       };
                cnode.attributes.rel = "root";
                cnode.attributes.mdata = "{draggable : true}";
                nodesList.Add(cnode);
            }
            else
            {

                var trees = _CategoryRepository.getAlltreesByCategoryID(id);

                IQueryable<tree> custom;

                if(revisionID != 0)
                {
                    custom = from c in trees
                              where
                                  c.AccountID == AccountID
                              select c;
                } else
                {
                    custom = from c in trees
                             where
                                 c.AccountID == AccountID && c.PublishedRevisionID != null && c.PublishedRevisionID != 0
                             select c;
                }

                var acme = from c in trees where c.AccountID == acmeContent.acmeID select c;

                foreach (var tree in (custom.Count() > 0) ? custom : acme)
                {
                    if(revisionID == 0 && tree.PublishedRevisionID == null) continue;
                    int tempRev = (revisionID != 0) ? revisionID : (int)tree.PublishedRevisionID;

                    if(custom.Count() == 1)
                    {
                        var tempNodes = _treeNodesRepository.GetNodesBytreeID(tree.treeID, null, tempUserID, tempRev);
                        nodesList.AddRange(tempNodes);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var cnode = new JsTreeNode();
                        cnode.attributes = new Attributes { id = tree.treeID.ToString(), title = tree.treeName };
                        cnode.data = new Data { title = tree.treeName };
                        cnode.children = _treeNodesRepository.GetNodesBytreeID(tree.treeID, null, tempUserID, tempRev);
                        cnode.attributes.rel = "Folder";

                        nodesList.Add(cnode);
                    }
                }
            }

            var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string res = ser.Serialize(nodesList);

            return Content(res,"application/json");

        }
```

...and Finally, the 'culprit', see how it calls itself:

```
public List<JsTreeNode> GetNodesByTreeID(int TreeID, int? parentID,int userID, int revisionID)
        {

            IQueryable<UserTreeNode> TreeNodes = GetAllTreeNodesByTreeIDAndParentNodeID(TreeID, parentID,userID,revisionID);
            List<JsTreeNode> nodesList = new List<JsTreeNode>();



            foreach (UserTreeNode node in TreeNodes)
            {
                string nodeName = node.Node.NodeName.Replace("'", "&#39;");

                JsTreeNode cnode = new JsTreeNode
                                       {
                                           attributes = new Attributes
                                                            {id = node.Node.TreeNodeID.ToString(),
                                                            title = nodeName},
                                           data = new Data {title = nodeName}
                                       };

                if(node.Node.ResourceID != null)
                {
                    cnode.attributes.complete = (node.IsComplete) ? "true" : "false";
                    cnode.attributes.rel = ResourceTypes.ReturnResourceTypeName(_resourceRepository.getResourceByID(Convert.ToInt32(node.Node.ResourceID)).ResourceTypeID);
                    cnode.attributes.href = "/resource/" + node.Node.ResourceID + "?minimal=true&nodeID=" + node.Node.TreeNodeID.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    var nodeChildren = GetNodesByTreeID(TreeID, node.Node.TreeNodeID,userID,revisionID);
                    if (nodeChildren.Count > 0)
                        cnode.children = nodeChildren;

                    cnode.attributes.complete = "false";
                    cnode.attributes.rel = "Folder";
                }

                nodesList.Add(cnode);
            }

            return nodesList;
        }
```

Comment: omg automatic properties, seriously.

Comment: Please elaborate, what does that mean? I didn't write this, I was just put on damage control. :)

Comment: Not an answer, but have you used Profiler to watch your queries hit the database?  I would bet you're either executing TONS of separate queries or are dragging down TONS of data.  Tree data structures can end up pretty massive in a short amount of time.

Comment: How can I do the Profiler thing, link me to a tutorial maybe?

Comment: @Shogun automatic property: `public string OMG {get;set;}` compare that to any single property in the code you posted.  Would decrap your source by about nine lines per property.

Comment: @Shogun I guess you've been tasked to do something way above your skill level.  Among the top three toughest tasks of software development is optimization.  I feel for ya.  [Profiler tutorial](http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5054787.html)

Comment: Also, StackOverflow works best when you limit the scope of your questions as much as possible.  If you get a solution to this question here you're a lucky lucky dev.

Comment: yeah I know that, I was just hoping someone might be able to glance at it and see something really standing out, but so far this Profiler idea is pointing me in the right direction I hope

Comment: I edited the the classes to include auto-implemented properties to at least reduce clutter in the question.

Comment: @Anthonly lol thanks, feels much better now.

Comment: Wow, awesomely done!  Code, db, everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best suggestion at this point in the process is to spin up [Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx) (different from Sql Profiler) and get an idea of what part of the process is actually taking the most amount of time.

If you don't have a version of VS with the profiler, you can [check out this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+application+profilers) for other application profilers.  First hit is for asp.net.

Comment: I'm also thinking that maybe instead of building this JSON content every time this tree is requested I can build it when the tree is CREATED and just save it in the DB for when the tree is requested.

Answer (score 1):

The tables you posted include an identity column, but these columns are not designated as primary keys (at least, not in the sample you show).

I'm unable to find your LinqToSql query constructions, so it's really hard to comment on optimization of the queries.  I suspect it's all contained within : `GetAllTreeNodesByTreeIDAndParentNodeID`

Run these statements individually in Sql Studio:

```
sp_help TreeNodes
sp_help TreeRevisions
```

The 6th result set is a list of indexes... in your case - this result set may be empty.  If you have no indexes, that's your #1 problem.

At a glance, I would recommend these indexes be added

```
TreeNodes
  TreeNodeID primary key
x TreeID nonclustered index
  TreeRevisionID nonclustered index
* TreeID, ParentNodeId nonclustered index

TreeRevisions
  TreeRevisionID primary key
  TreeID nonclustered index
```

That one marked with a * is probably the most important one for your current way of querying.  Column order is important in a multi-column index.

Also consider fetching the whole tree by TreeId and doing more filtering/shaping in memory.  This will avoid recursive/repetitive querying in the database.  With this approach, the index marked with an x is the significant one.